# About using Rails online documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys
I'm new to Rails
I found this code in the default application_controller.rb which generate by rails generator

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

And then after I check the protect_from_forgery method in online documentation, I found it's in ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection module not the ActionController::Base

Could Anybody tell me why, and how to check the method I can use of ApplicationController class

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the ActionController::Base incude ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection

You can see all module include in ActionController::Base : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Answer (score 1):

You can mixin functionality into your class by using modules.
This is a feature of ruby inheritance.

So, if it is module you are using, you can `require` it and then `include` it to mixin the functionality provided by the module into your class.

More about mixins here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out